# How to scale a tikzcd diagram

Tags: tikz-styles, tikz-cd

**Question:**

> I want to scale a tikzcd diagram, but it doesn't seem to be working. It always compiles in a small scale. How does one scale a tikzcd diagram to, say, large scale?

**Attempt:**

I tried to set the option scale but it doesn't do anyhting.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tizk-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[scale=2.7em]
 X \arrow{d}[swap]{\mathcal Q} \arrow{r}{f}  &Z \\ 
 Y \arrow{ru}[swap]{\bar f} &{}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

I've also read the manual [tikz-cd 0.9e](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf) but I don't understand how to use the command /tikz/commutative diagrams/ row step=\langle size \rangle or its variances. I believe I'm using the latest version of tikz-cd and pgf files.

**Note**: I'm not interested in tikzpicture or similar environments, I'm working with tikzcd.

Comment: have you tried `transform canvas={scale=<number>}`?

Comment: I haven't tried this. Where do I use it?

Comment: Do you want to scale everything, including the fonts?

Comment: @Bernard Yes, if possible. I want to scale everything.

Comment: instead of your `scale`

Comment: Why not a simple `scalebox` then?

Comment: @domenicocamasta It gives the error: "I don't know the key /tikz/tansform canvas {scale= 2.7em}"

Comment: you're missing a `=` sign: `transform canvas={scale=2}`

Comment: @domenicocamasta It worked, but it's huge now and it's on top of the text.

Comment: I know, change the value according to your needs : )

Comment: @domenicocamasta Still not quite though. I adjusted but the diagram is all over the text.

Comment: @Bernard I'm having trouble using \scalebox. It's not compiling.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\adjustbox{scale=2,center}{%
    \begin{tikzcd}
    X \arrow{d}[swap]{\mathcal Q} \arrow{r}{f} &Z \\
    Y \arrow{ru}[swap]{\bar f} &{}
    \end{tikzcd}
}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is \lipsum[1] necessary?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: One may as well choose \lipsum[2] or whatver value ;o) More seriously I wanted to make visible the size discrepancy between normal tex and what is obtained using `\adjustbox`, which is questionable, in my opinion.

Answer (score 11):

It depends on what scale precisely means. Naively one would think the only reasonable thing to scale was the `column sep` and/or `row sep`. This is discussed extensively on p. 6 of the `tikz-cd` manual.

Let's assume that one wants to scale the texts. They come in form of cells and edge labels. One can thus define a combined transformation via

```
\tikzcdset{scale cd/.style={every label/.append style={scale=#1},
    cells={nodes={scale=#1}}}}
```

Examples:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzcdset{scale cd/.style={every label/.append style={scale=#1},
    cells={nodes={scale=#1}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
 X \arrow{d}[swap]{\mathcal{Q}} \arrow{r}{f}  &Z \\ 
 Y \arrow{ru}[swap]{\bar f}
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}[scale cd=2]
 X \arrow{d}[swap]{\mathcal{Q}} \arrow{r}{f}  &Z \\ 
 Y \arrow{ru}[swap]{\bar f}
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}[scale cd=2.7]
 X \arrow{d}[swap]{\mathcal{Q}} \arrow{r}{f}  &Z \\ 
 Y \arrow{ru}[swap]{\bar f}
\end{tikzcd}


\begin{tikzcd}[scale cd=2,sep=large]
 X \arrow{d}[swap]{\mathcal{Q}} \arrow{r}{f}  &Z \\ 
 Y \arrow{ru}[swap]{\bar f}
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}[scale cd=2.7,sep=huge]
 X \arrow{d}[swap]{\mathcal{Q}} \arrow{r}{f}  &Z \\ 
 Y \arrow{ru}[swap]{\bar f}
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]