# How to resize tikzcd figure to fit in beamer frame?

Tags: beamer, tikz-cd

I am preparing my slides using beamer. My working code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgf,tikz,tikz-cd}

\usetikzlibrary{calc, arrows, backgrounds, fit, positioning, quotes, shapes, shapes.geometric, intersections, decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[fragile]
        \frametitle{Introduction}
        \framesubtitle{Background and motivation}
        \begin{figure}[h!]
            \label{figure:maptoR}
            \begin{center}
                \[
                \begin{tikzcd}[cells={nodes={circle,align=center,inner sep=1pt,
                            text width={width("$\mathrm{Row}_i\times\mathrm{Row}_i$")},draw,
                            path picture={\path[ball color=gray!60,fill opacity=0.4]
                                (path picture bounding box.center) 
                                circle[radius={width("$\mathrm{Row}_i\times\mathrm{Row}_i$")*1pt}];
                    }}},
                    bend angle=50,every arrow/.append style={-stealth,bend left},
                    every label/.append style={font=\normalsize},
                    sep=small]
                    M_n\times M_n \arrow[r,"R_i"]
                    \arrow[rrrr,bend right=25,"\succ",start anchor=-60,end anchor=-120]
                    &  \mathrm{Row}_i\times \mathrm{Row}_i \arrow[r,"\omega_{ij}"]
                    & M_n \arrow[r,"\omega_{ij}'"]
                    & M_{1\times n} \arrow[r,"\omega^*"l]
                    & \mathbb{R}\\
                \end{tikzcd}
                \]\caption{Composition of function $\succ$.}
            \end{center}
        \end{figure}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

What do I need to do so that the figure fit in the frame nicely? Please help.

Comment: You can use an `\adjustbox` with the corresponding package as explained here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/325309/118712 or scale each cell like in the other answer to the same question https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/547908/118712

Comment: Unrelated, but maybe useful to you: the `\[` `\]` don't seem to do anything and it is ususally recommended to use `\centering` instead of the `center` environment, because the latter adds spaces before and after your figure, which on a `beamer` frame is normally not what you want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to scale a tikzcd diagram](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/325297/how-to-scale-a-tikzcd-diagram)