# How to keep the equation number in the line of a enlarged tikzcd diagram?

Tags: tikz-cd

In the following `MWE`,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{tikzcd}  
    \cdot \arrow[r,"m"] \arrow[rr,"h", bend left=40]& \cdot \arrow[r,"e"] & \cdot \arrow[r,shift left=.75ex,"f"]
    \arrow[r,shift right=.75ex,swap,"g"] & \cdot
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=3.2em]  
    \cdot \arrow[r,"m"] \arrow[rr,"h", bend left=40]& \cdot \arrow[r,"e"] & \cdot \arrow[r,shift left=.75ex,"f"]
    \arrow[r,shift right=.75ex,swap,"g"] & \cdot
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\adjustbox{scale=1.5,center}{%
    \begin{tikzcd} 
    \cdot \arrow[r,"m"] \arrow[rr,"h", bend left=40]& \cdot \arrow[r,"e"] & \cdot \arrow[r,shift left=.75ex,"f"]
    \arrow[r,shift right=.75ex,swap,"g"] & \cdot
    \end{tikzcd}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I'd like to enlarge the `tikz-cd` diagram of (1). The first solution (2), using `column sep` option, does not enlarge the letters representing the objects of the diagram. The second solution (3), employing an `adjustbox`, almost does the job, except the equation number is overflown to the next line. So, how can I keep the equation number at its correct place regardless of what value I pick for `scale` option of `adjustbox`?

[image]

Comment: In `scalebox` remove option `center`.

Comment: As Zarko points out, `center` will make the adjusted box as wide as the text width.

Comment: @egreg: Yes. Thanks to both of you.

Comment: Is it too late to say this is a bad idea anyway: If you just scale the entire box you'll get mismatching font sizes -> typographically bad!

Comment: @Skillmon: Do you have any alternative suggestion?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I have no experience in using `tikzcd`, a simple `scale=1.5` in the options doesn't do the expected thing, so all in all: No, sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

See this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/547908/101651.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\tikzcdset{scale cd/.style={every label/.append style={scale=#1},
    cells={nodes={scale=#1}}}}
    
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{tikzcd}  
    \cdot \arrow[r,"m"] \arrow[rr,"h", bend left=40]& \cdot \arrow[r,"e"] & \cdot \arrow[r,shift left=.75ex,"f"]
    \arrow[r,shift right=.75ex,swap,"g"] & \cdot
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{tikzcd}[scale cd=1.5] 
    \cdot \arrow[r,"m"] \arrow[rr,"h", bend left=40]& \cdot \arrow[r,"e"] & \cdot \arrow[r,shift left=.75ex,"f"]
    \arrow[r,shift right=.75ex,swap,"g"] & \cdot
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]